# CreateUploadSession fails on a OneDrive business account but is works ok on a personal account

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-graph-api

My request looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myfolder/myfilename:/createUploadSession
```

with this header:

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

and this json body:

```
{\"item\":{\"@odata.type\":\"microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties\",\"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\":\"replace\",\"fileSize\":\(fileSize!)},\"deferCommit\":false}"
```

This works fine on a personal OneDrive account but fails with an "Invalid Request" error on a business account.

I'm using MSAL to authenticate to MSGraph.

Do we need to do something different for a business accounts ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all the items properties one by one and figured out that the business account does not like the filesize item nor the deferCommit.
I'm able to add the conflictBehaviour and it pass.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/525) for more details.

See also [Service issue report](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-serviceissues/issues/17#issuecomment-705577628)