# CreateUploadSession for OneDrive upload using Microsoft Graph API: The request is malformed or incorrect

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

Using MSAL 1.1.24 & making API calls in an iOS app that supports uploading to OneDrive for a year now.
Some users reported that they sometimes (not 100% of the time) see their upload fail.
The error message is "The request is malformed or incorrect".
Attached is a screenshot with the full error message returned by the servers:

[image]

Whats is wrong in the URL?

This is how I create the request:

```
/* REQUEST */
guard let validPathForURL = uploadPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: "\(ODManager.kGraphEndpoint)"+validPathForURL+":/createUploadSession") else {
    DLog("Invalid URL")
        completion(QSTransferResult.failure(QSTransferError.ResourceNotFound), nil)
          return
}
var request = ODManager.shared.createURLRequestWithToken(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
// Conflict management
let fileExistBehavior = fileExistProcedure == .keepBoth ? "rename" : "replace"
let params = ["item": [
              "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":fileExistBehavior,
              "name":fileName],
              "fileSize":fileSize,
             ] as [String : Any] // name must be the same as the one mentioned in the URL (in other words, the file name must be in both place)

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
```

The server returning the issue:
[image]

Comment: Can you show what your request looks like?

Comment: Just added code to show how it is built. I cannot reproduce the issue, only some users seem to have it, but I could not yet identify a specific workflow triggering the issue.

Comment: I drilled in a little more and I'm now confident the reason for the failure is what I stated in my answer. What's unclear based on your code is how that could be the case. I know `JSONSerialization` does support sorting, but 1) you need to specify the option and 2) it wouldn't result in non-deterministic behavior. If it's not something in the app the only other possibility is some other entity applying the sort, but given it's an HTTPS request that also seems unlikely.

Comment: @Brad, the users reporting the issue have one common point: they upload to a German server (cfr screenshot added to the main post). Could it be a lead?

Comment: @Brad another user reported today, the same issue, coming from the very same Germany West Central server. Could it be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, that was as a matter of fact, only happening on business accounts.
It turns out that you cannot use the fileSize parameter on these accounts.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64225439/2040156

It should be fixed on Microsoft side imho, to avoid a lot of time lost. What's the point of this difference anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this... I think when it's failing the `@name.conflictBehavior` annotation is NOT the first property in the JSON document provided to the service (it doesn't actually have to be first - it can be after another instance annotations, but NOT properties). Now the fact that it doesn't happen often is a little odd... is it possible the annotation is only added on occasion (e.g. when a conflict is detected you pop up UI to ask if the user wants to overwrite)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a small portion of code showing how I build the request, including the conflict management (i.e. : `@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior`). It is always first in the parameters. (The user is not prompted in case of conflict, the procedure (rename/replace) is a global parameter.

Comment: Documentation is contradictory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0   ---> says that ```The parameter @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior should be included in the URL instead of the body of the request.```. While https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0 ---> says that ```you can specify properties in the request body to provide more information about the file being uploaded and to customize the semantics of the upload operation.``` and includes the conflictBehavior annotation in the body !??